# angular6 angularfire not initialized

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2'
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
import { MatButtonModule, MatCheckboxModule, MatInputModule } from '@angular/material';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { LoginRoutingModule } from './login-routing.module';
import { LoginComponent } from './login.component';


@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        LoginRoutingModule,
        MatInputModule,
        MatCheckboxModule,
        MatButtonModule,
        FlexLayoutModule,
        FormsModule, 
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
        AngularFirestoreModule,
        AngularFireAuthModule, 
    ],
    declarations: [LoginComponent]
})

export class LoginModule {}
```

above is the code which  for my login module it throw a error on the  console no default app is initialised

> FirebaseError {code: "app/no-app", message: "Firebase: No Firebase App
>   '[DEFAULT]' has been cre…- call Firebase App.initializeApp()
>   (app/no-app).", name: "[DEFAULT]", stack: "[DEFAULT]: Firebase: No
>   Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' h…ontext
>   (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:56563:25)"}

How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

As per the docs, you need to initialize the `AngularfireModule()` app wide, i.e. in the `app.module.ts`. And the you can define which module you want to import in the submodules.

Add these in `app.module.ts` and remove these from `login.module.ts`

```
AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
AngularFirestoreModule,
AngularFireAuthModule,
```

Please refer to the [official docs.](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/install-and-setup.md)